# How can I do this as a single interface?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I need to use multiple interfaces in the structure block. How can I do this as a single interface? There are 4 now, but this number will increase even more. So can I do this using only 1 interface?

My Desing INFO :

1. IClientServices => GetToken
2. CustomerClient (not interface) => Get - Post - Put etc. Connect API with HttpClient
3. ICsutomerApiService => First Method : GetCustomer with dapper Sql Second Method : CreateCustomer new model mapping (CheckExist) and then send this data API
4. This code windows service. It will run in the background and start to this service, I check the data I get from the db and send it to the API.

   ```
   #region Variables
    private readonly ISettingsService _settingsServce;
    private readonly ICustomerApiService _customerApiService;
    private readonly IProductApiService _productApiService;
    private readonly IProductPriceApiService _productPriceApiService;
    private readonly SettingsDto _settings;
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    #endregion

   #region Constructure
    public CallBackService(ISettingsService settingsService, ICustomerApiService customerApiService, 
        IProductApiService productApiService, IProductPriceApiService productPriceApiService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _settingsServce = settingsService;
        _customerApiService = customerApiService;
        _productApiService = productApiService;
        _productPriceApiService = productPriceApiService;

        _settings = _settingsServce.Get();
        _timer = new Timer();
    } 
    #endregion
   ```

Comment: you could `compose` a object that contains the required DI, then simply inject  the `composed` object.

Comment: @Jazb I tried this but this object requested the interfaces it depends on as parameters.

Comment: Anything you do will likely will likely just be hiding dependencies behind another level of abstraction (which can be even more suspect). In short, there is nothing wrong with having a certain amount of services in a constructor, if you have too many services, you likely have a larger design problem anyway and is a candidate for refactoring .

Comment: @TheGeneral : "you likely have a larger design problem anyway." yes maybe :( but I know; 
 think there is a way !

Comment: 4 dependencies is hardly anything worth worry about, and wanting to hide them is bordering on OCD :) you should have bigger things to worry about... Put them on new lines, it will make you feel better

Comment: @TheGeneral 3 more to come :)

Comment: That is still not a huge concern at all. Assuming this is for Dependency injection, your options are creating a special class to hide them (meh), Property injection if your framework has it (double meh), something like *MediatR* which just hides everything (\*groan sigh\*)

Comment: Have you [read the docs on aggregate services](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/aggregate-services.html)?

Comment: @TravisIllig thx this works for me :)